# Printing Selected Data that the Pi gets from a serial connection then opening a file named that data

Tags: python, arduino, rfid, nfc

HI After hours of research I've come to ask the people for help, I have this simple script

```
import serial 
serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",115200,timeout=1)

     while 1:
           print serialport.readline(),

serialport.close()
```

The script's function is to Grab Data from an Arduino and Display it On the Pi. 
What I want to do is Take all the data and only print 1 string of data. Example

On my Arduino I have the this set to print a UID of my RFID Card

```
// Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");
```

The Data I'm getting on the PI is as follows

```
Found an ISO14443A card
  UID Length: 4 bytes
  UID Value: 0x3A 0xDE 0x4D 0x02
```

I don't want to Display all this data I just want the UID Value: So my end Result is "UID Value: 0x3A 0xDE 0x4D 0x02" or whatever the UID of the card is not the other data

The next step I need help with as I'm clueless with this is Take the UID Value remove the spaces so its a single string remove its name and remove the 0x so it looks like "3ADE4D02" and run a sh file named that string so it would run 3ADE4D02.sh

TL:DR I want to take the UID from a serial Connection and open an sh file named that UID

Any Ideas?

Comment: This appears to be a Python programming question - ask on a programming site.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your serial read is working properly so I will deal only with the second part.

```
for line in serialport.readline():
  if "UID Value:" in line:
    filename = ''.join([word[2:] if word.startswith('0x') else '' for word in line.split()])+'.sh'
```

you can then use `os.system(filedir+filename)` to run the sh file, assuming you know what the filedir is.

EDIT: make sure to have `line.split()` instead of `line` in list comprehension, I realized that strings iterate through each letter, not each word.